# Bars in a bar chart are close to each other in Libreoffice calc

Tags: charts, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/739812/libreoffice-calc-how-can-i-create-a-custom-legend) to create a chart like this:
[image: Image with different legends]

By following the tutorial, I create different data series and data names to create different legends. The problem I am facing is the fact that all the bars are close to each other, but I want them separated.

I tried to click in one of the bars with right button of my mouse, selected *Format Data Series*, clicked in *Options* tab and adjusted the Spacing setting, like [in this post](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/12293/reduce-inter-space-between-diagram-bars/). But all bars are moved and seems like there is only one bar in the chart, which is composed of all bars.

What I did wrong here? is the process of creating different legends I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a negative value for the `Overlap` property on the `Options` tab of the `Format Data Series` dialog:

The following settings (negative value of `-50%`) ...

[image]

...should give the following result:

[image]

Contrary, a positive value for `Overlap`...

[image]

...will give the opposite result:

[image]